# Prove if $g \circ f$ is $1-1$ and $f$ is onto, show that $g$ is $1-1$

Tags: functions, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $g: B \rightarrow C$. $g \circ f: A \rightarrow C$.

But where do I use the fact that $f$ is onto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $g(x)=g(y)$ for $x,y\in B$. Then, **because $f$ is onto**, there are $a$ and $b$ in $A$ such that $f(a)=x$ and $f(b)=y$. But then $g\circ f(a)=g\circ f(b)$, implying $a=b$ since $g\circ f$ is injective. This gives $x=f(a)=f(b)=y$.

Answer (score 2):

> But where do I use the fact that $f$ is onto?

Counterexamples when $f$ is not onto are easy to come by: consider $A=C=\{a\}$, $B=\{a,b\}$ and any $f:A\to B$ (this fully determines $g$, which is not one-to-one).

If you do not like minimal examples, consider $A=B=C=\mathbb N_0$ and the functions  $f:n\mapsto n+1$ and $g:n\mapsto (n-1)^+$.